# Colorbox code working outside of Umbraco, but not within

Tags: javascript, jquery, umbraco, colorbox

We are new to Umbraco and coding within it, so I thank you in advance for your patience and assistance.

In short, we created a 'test' page utilizing a colorbox pop-up to display a form.  It works perfectly in the test page.

When trying to integrate the code into Umbraco, when the "Request Info" button is clicked, the form opens in a full page, and the colorbox does not display.

I would appreciate any assistance that you could provide.

Test link (working):

http://online.saintleo.edu/Colorbox/Untitled-1.html

Example of a page where the "Request Info" button (yellow on right) opens full page, and NOT colorbox:

http://online.saintleo.edu/academics/masters-programs/master-of-accounting-(macc).aspx

I've spent the entire weekend trying to find the solution, hoping to get this resolved ASAP.

Thank you in advance, I appreciate your time and assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a problem with how you have implemented your script in Umbraco. Just looking through Chrome's browser inspector, I can see that your script is failing to find the colorbox objects which means that something is prevent the library from being available. This is usually because a dependent javascript library has failed.

Looking at your source code, you are loading all your jQuery libraries at the bottom of your page. This is good practice, but you have placed your a second jQuery file reference, your colorbox file references and the custom colorbox code in the head of the page.

There are several things you will need to do:

- Remove the jQuery reference from the head of the page;
- Move the colorbox file references to the bottom of the page, after all the other javascript file references. You can leave the colorbox CSS file reference in the head.
- Move the custom colorbox code to after all the other javascript file references. I usually place this kind of code in a separate file.

Depending on your Umbraco implementation:

- If you are using masterpages, use a `ContentPlaceholder` to allow templates to drop javascript file references into the bottom of the page;
- If you are using MVC views, use a footer `section` to do the same

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help. I think I've done what you asked, but, I'm still getting the full page instead of colorbox popup.  One thing to note is that the jQuery version used by the developers to build the site was 1.5.2.  When I try to use this version outside of Umbraco to test the colorbox, it doesn't work either.  My test page that I created uses 1.9.1.  When I try to replace the 1.5.2 in the main.master file, it breaks the site.  I also am new to the ContentPlaceHolder idea so not sure if I still need to try that or not.  Could you please take a look again? Thanks so much.

Comment: It looks like the change you have made has removed the closing `</script>` tag of the google analytics script.

Comment: Digbyswift - I can't thank you enough.  I am new at this and have been trying to fix all weekend.  It is finally working.  You are a lifesaver.  I thank you so very much for taking the time to help me!